# How to render geojson polygon in React leaflet MapContainer?

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, geojson, react-leaflet

Stack : Reactjs, Leafletjs, EsriLeafletjs

I am trying to display one Polygon in GeoJson on a leaflet map container. My main issue is when I use Leaflet.geoJson(data) it return invalid JSON object.

Please have a look ...

My JSON file looks like this. It is containing one polygon.
https://gist.githubusercontent.com/UmairMughal901/d43ee77a9be27f2dcd006038fe8f07e7/raw/8650f4f3585ff0c1706da7a434251cfc70f1907b/map.geojson

My Map Component

```
    import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
    import * as L from 'leaflet';
    import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';
    import * as EL from "esri-leaflet";
    import axios from 'axios';
    import { GeoJSON } from 'react-leaflet';

    export default function Mapfun() {
      const mapCanvas = useRef(null);
    
      const dataParcel = axios.get('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/UmairMughal901/d43ee77a9be27f2dcd006038fe8f07e7/raw/8650f4f3585ff0c1706da7a434251cfc70f1907b/map.geojson').then(resp => {
    
        console.log(resp.data);
      });
    
    
      useEffect(() => {
        mapCanvas.current = L.map('mapdiv', {
          center: [31, 72],
          zoom: 6,
          layers: [
            L.tileLayer("http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
              attribution:
                '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
            }),
            EL.featureLayer({ url: 'http://localhost:6080/arcgis/rest/services/Pu/PB_/MapServer/11' }),
  //Main Issue here          
L.geoJSON(dataParcel),
    
    
          ]
        })
    
        
      }
        );
    
      //todo 
    
    
      return (
        <div id='mapdiv' style={{ width: '100%' }}>
        </div>
    
      )
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`const dataParcel = axios.get` is not what you think it is.  `axios.get` is an asynchronous function, so dataParcel is not the result of what was returned from the Promise, but rather the promise itself.  You need to do this in proper [async/await syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).  In react-leaflet, this is made even easier.  You don't need to be working with `L.map` at all, reat-leaflet has you covered.

Create a component specifically for your data fetching, which will fetch data on mount, and render a react-leaflet GeoJSON when the data is ready:

```js
const MyData = () => {
  // create state variable to hold data when it is fetched
  const [data, setData] = React.useState();

  // useEffect to fetch data on mount
  useEffect(() => {
    // async function!
    const getData = async () => {
      // 'await' the data
      const response = await axios.get("url");
      // save data to state
      setData(response.data);
    };
    getData();
  }, []);

  // render react-leaflet GeoJSON when the data is ready
  if (data) {
    return <GeoJSON data={data} />;
  } else {
    return null;
  }
};


// Use your component in a MapContainer
const Map = (props) => {
  return (
    <MapContainer {...mapcontainerprops}>
      <MyData />
    </MapContainer>
  );
};
```

### [Working Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/async-esri-leaflet-yxrtr)

<sub>Also, for funsies, if you are working with esri-leaflet components in a react-leaflet application, you might try [react-esri-leaflet](https://github.com/slutske22/react-esri-leaflet).</sub>

Comment: Thank you. Explained very well. I am new to this technology. It's working.